# Add spaces to variable in shell script

Tags: shell, sh, spaces

I want create a yaml configuration file from a sh script. So I need to add multiple spaces to a variable like that:

```
SERVERS=""
for i in $(seq 1 5); do
    SERVERS="$SERVERS      -server`printf "%03d" $i`.$URL\n"
done
```

But the spaces are reduced to only one space. How do I ensure that the spaces aren't replaced?

Comment: Note that you aren't adding newlines to your string; you are adding two literal characters "\" and "n".

Comment: I realized this already. When I print the variable by echo "$SERVERS", the \n is interpreted as a newline, but when I store it in a file, it just dumps "\n". How do I make a real line break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you forgot to use double quotes when you echo `$SERVER` =)

```
SERVERS=""
for i in $(seq 1 5); do
    SERVERS="$SERVERS      -server$(printf "%03d" $i).$URL\n"
done
echo "$SERVER"
```

Output :

```
      -server001.\n      -server002.\n      -server003.\n      -server004.\n(...)
```

That's the rules of the (not so) terrific [*word splitting*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html)

---

Another solution using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -le 'for (1..5) { print "   -server$_"}' | tee -a file.yaml
```

Or using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1; i<=5; i++) print "   -server"++c}'  |
    tee -a file.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks, I really just forgot to add double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

What do you ultimately do with `SERVERS`? Rather than try to build up a multi-line string, something like this might be better:

```
for i in $(seq 1 5); do
    echo "     -server$(printf "%03d" $i).$URL"
done >> file
```